# Replacing nth occurence of a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a MySQL Table with several rows and columns.

I want to to replace the second occurrence of a string in a particular column for all rows.

This string has several occurrences. (Upto 10 times, but I want to replace only the second occurrence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQLv8.0 you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

> REGEXP_REPLACE(expr, pat, repl[, pos[, occurrence[, match_type]]])

So if you want to start searching from position 1 and replace only the 2nd occurence of the match you can use 1,2 as the last two options:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field`=REGEXP_REPLACE(`field`,'search_string','replacement_string',1, 2);
```

**Note:There was a bug report for MySql Version:    8.0.11 that was fixed in 8.0.12.**

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90870

Before using in production test that you have the right MySql version and it works for you.